# Java Callback from C code in library loaded by a non-java application

Tags: java

Working with gstreamer to process images from a video stream and use java for gstreamer which handles the expected audio/image data types. We have a specific program in the gstreamer pipeline that will run a deep learning model on the image resulting in meta data. In addition to the image we want the metadata about what was detected in the image. The gstreamer hook for this is to tell the deep learning module a custom DLL/Lib to call and it will pass the metadata to the appropriate function in the DLL/Lib. We would like the DLL/Lib to callback into a Java method with the data for the gstreamer instance it started to process the image.

We have it working with a memory based pipeline to share the the metadata but not as elegant as it should be. We are working on trying to use shared memory by name between Java and C library to solve the problem where Java doesn't have a reference to the DLL that was created by the external code doing the image processing.

Definitaly understand the security concerns on why a DLL/Lib should not be able to call a Java method in a specific running java application.

Any C library experts know any singleton tricks that would allow Java to pass in the appropraite callback functional pointer to a DLL/Lib instance that would common to all instances of that DLL/Lib when loaded by external applications?

Looking for a C library approach to share a functional pointer for a Java callback method where Java didn't load the library

Answer (score 0):

> Any C library experts know any singleton tricks that would allow Java to pass in the appropraite callback functional pointer to a DLL/Lib instance that would common to all instances of that DLL/Lib when loaded by external applications?

As I understand what you're asking, such a thing is not possible.  Shared libraries do not provide a mechanism for inter-process communication.  When a shared library contains modifiable variables, each process using the library has its own copies of those.  If you need IPC then use one of the usual IPC mechanisms: shared memory, pipes / fifos, *etc*..

Even standard IPC is not sufficient or appropriate for a callback interface, however.  One process cannot call functions / invoke methods in a different process's context.  Anything that allowed that would constitute a critical flaw in the OS.  If you really need a function-call-like interface for IPC then maybe you're looking for a remote procedure call mechanism, or some client of client / server architecture.  Or maybe your existing "memory based pipeline" is not as inelegant as you suppose.